Irregular grid construction for contour plot
I am trying to construct a contour plot using matplotlib in Python with an irregular xy-grid. My x-data is made up of 10 arrays, each having 500 elements. These 500 elements are different for each of the 10 arrays. An example would be:
x = np.random.random_sample(size = (10,50))
print(x)
y = np.random.random_sample(size = 10)
print(y)
z = np.random.random_sample(size = (10,50))
print(z)

So I am asking how to visualize this set of data as a contour or heatmap. Along y[0] on the plot, x[0] axis values match up with the z[0] data, etc. I'm using pickle to write and extract dictionary data:
# Read data from a file
with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data_loaded = pickle.load(f)

x, y, z = data_loaded['eigenenergies'], data_loaded['r_primes'], data_loaded['dc_intensities']

My usual plotting doesn't work.
# Create meshgrid
xmesh, ymesh = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Reshape z to match x and y dimensions
N = len(x)
M = len(y)
z = z.reshape(N, M)

# Increase the number of levels for smoother color transitions
num_levels = 1000  # Adjust as needed

# Plot contour
#plt.contour(xmesh, ymesh, z)
#plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z, shading='flat', vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max())
plt.contourf(xmesh, ymesh, z, levels=np.linspace(z.min(), z.max(), num_levels))

# Add color bar
colorbar = plt.colorbar()
colorbar.set_label(r"Intensity")  # Set the label for the colorbar

# Add labels and title (optional)
plt.xlabel(r'$E \;\;[J]$')
plt.ylabel(r'$r^, \;[\AA]$')
plt.title('DC')

# Show the plot
plt.show()

I am not sure how to move forward with this. I tried creating a regular meshgrid by forming a linspace in x, with np.min(x) and np.max(x) as the bounds. I also tried several Copilot prompts to see if AI could give me some idea of where to start, but every suggestion had the x and y data as similar dimensions.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour. It is not clear how your data is formatted, how the data points relate to one another (i.e. how the data is interpreted), what your expected result is, or what error you're currently getting. Please edit your post (not just comment) to clarify your problem. Also, please share a minimal reproducible example so we can run your code.

plt.tricontourf(...) works with non-meshed data. That might work better in your situation.

@jared I've added a blurb on constructing data that has similar shapes. Unfortunately, I don't know if posting the code that generates the real data would be helpful because it requires diagonalizing a Hamiltonian in a loop. Each set of eigenvectors (found over each loop iteration) is used as a projection basis... etc. It's pretty complicated, but the gist I think is embodied in the random generator I added to the original question. Please let me know if there's something else to add.

Here is a solution to my problem:
dim = 50

# Read data from a file
with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data_loaded = pickle.load(f)

x, y, z = data_loaded['eigenenergies'], data_loaded['r_primes'], data_loaded['dc_intensities']

X = np.array(x)
Y = np.array(y)
Z = np.array(z)

# Create a DataFrame with your data
data = pd.DataFrame({'x': X.flatten(), 'y': np.repeat(Y, dim), 'z': Z.flatten()})

# Pivot the data to create a 2D grid
Z = data.pivot_table(index='x', columns='y', values='z').T.values
X_unique = np.sort(data.x.unique())
Y_unique = np.sort(data.y.unique())
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X_unique, Y_unique)

# Replace nan values with zeros
Z_cleaned = np.nan_to_num(Z)


plt.contourf(X, Y, Z_cleaned, levels=10, cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel(r'$\Delta E \; [|J|]$', fontsize=17)
plt.ylabel(r'$r^, \; [\AA]$', fontsize=17)
plt.xlim(0,1)
plt.show()

